# peculiar behavior with strrchr function

Tags: php, email

I was testing the strrchr function and was baffled by its behaviors. It is supposed to return the substring from the last occurrence of the matching pattern. For instance,

```
$test = 'example@hotmail.com';
echo strrchr($test,'@') ;
```

this returns the substring from the "@", that is @hotmail.com, but if I search for this "hot"

```
$test = 'example@hotmail.com';
echo strrchr($test,'example') ;
```

instead of tmail.com (I expected), how come it returns hotmail.com, and if I search for other patterns, the results are strange too. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only first character is used for searching, based on php documentation:

> If needle contains more than one character, only the first is used.
>   This behavior is different from that of strstr().

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

Comment: +1'd, according to SO your post was only 11 seconds behind mine. ;)

Comment: Yeah, great timing :) +1 for you :>

Answer (score 2):

Whenever programming, be sure to check the documentation. The [strrchr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) function does not do what you think it does:

> This function returns the portion of *haystack* which starts at the
>   last occurrence of *needle* and goes until the end of *haystack*.
>
> If *needle* contains more than one character, only the first is used.
>   This behavior is different from that of [strstr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

You probably wanted the [strstr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function in the first place.